Solving $\frac{\sqrt{26 + \sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{26 - \sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt[3]{26 + \sqrt{x}} + \sqrt[3]{26 - \sqrt{x}}} = \frac{5\sqrt{2}}{4}$
I'm trying to solve this equation for $x$ analytically. By hit and trial, I know $x=675$ is a solution to the equation. However, I could not find other solutions (if they exist) or prove that no other solutions exist.
$$\frac{\sqrt{26 + \sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{26 - \sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt[3]{26 + \sqrt{x}} + \sqrt[3]{26 - \sqrt{x}}} = \frac{5\sqrt{2}}{4}$$
Could someone give me some guidance in solving this equation completely? Thank you!

what have you tried?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Do you require $x$ to be real? Do you require $\sqrt{x}$ to be real? Do you require $\sqrt{26-\sqrt{x}}$ to be real? Depending on your answers, you might want to prove a certain function is strictly increasing for $0\le x\le 676$, giving the unique root $x=675$.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... Even when you're completely stumped, you can provide useful context. If this is a class exercise, tell us the topic(s) covered so far that seem relevant. If it's an online challenge/contest, indicate what the target audience is expected to know. Sometimes, just "thinking out loud" about things you know can get you going, and it can help others avoid explaining things you already understand. ... In any case, the more you can show that you're personally invested in finding a solution, the more likely it is that others will become invested in helping you with the search.

HINT
Let $u = \sqrt[6]{26 + \sqrt{x}}$ and $v = \sqrt[6]{26 - \sqrt{x}}$.
Then the proposed equation is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\frac{u^{3} - v^{3}}{u^{2} + v^{2}} = \frac{5\sqrt{2}}{4}
\end{align*}
Given that $u^{6} + v^{6} = 52$, can you take it from here?

As several comments suggested, some context would be helpful. Are you looking for real or complex solutions?
Anyway, as a first step toward a solution, try using the substitution $a=26-\sqrt{x}$ and $52-a=26+\sqrt{x}$. This simplifies the LHS somewhat.
